# How to set programmatically "Hides bottom bar on push"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am building a view programmatically from a tableview which has a bottom tab bar.
I would like this bottom bar to disappear when a table cell is selected.
I can do that using:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

but the size of the view remains as if the tabbar was still there.
I see that if the view is built on the storyboard and by setting the checkmark "Hides bottom bar on push", the view resizes to occupy the space left free by the tabbar. 
How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.anotherViewController animated:animated];
```

and for a specific view controller which your pushing. use this code

```
    TheViewController* theController = [[TheViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TheViewController" bundle:nil];
    theController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theController animated:YES];
    [theController release];
```

now the tabbar will be hidden and shown autometically. enjoy the time :)

Comment: I did that, but the problem is that the tabbar remains hidden when getting back to the tableview. Is there a way to display that tabbar again when finished with the detail view?

Comment: this will hide jst a specific view controller

Comment: YESSS! thank you. I spent hours on this literally :( and you solved it in a few secs :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Swift`:

```swift
let viewController = CustomViewController()
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```